# Problem setting cursor colors in vimrc: suppress the `-ne` that is written to my xterm on exit

Tags: vimrc, cursor, color

Following the `vim` manual and also some threads on this site, I can set the color of my cursor to orange in insert mode and red otherwise, with the following lines in my `.vimrc` file.

```
" use an orange cursor in insert mode
let &t_SI = "\<Esc>]12;orange\x7"
"use a red cursor otherwise
let &t_EI = "\<Esc>]12;red\x7"
silent !echo -ne "\033]12;red\007"
autocmd VimLeave * silent !echo -ne "\033]112\007"
```

The problem is that when run `vi` from an `xterm`, then when I exit `vi`, the string `-ne` is echo-ed in the terminal, which is quite annoying.      The source is the `echo` commands in the last two lines of the above code fragment.  If I comment the two lines  out the problem doesn't arise.   But I need them for the cursor color changes to work in vi and revert back to black when exiting.    What causes the `-ne` on exit, and how can I prevent it?     Thanks for any advice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Ditch `echo -ne`, for life. Use `printf`.

The Echo command is a portability nightmare; [POSIX does not even specify the `-e` flag and actually says](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/echo.html)

> If the first operand is `-n`, or if any of the operands contain a <backslash> character, the results are implementation-defined.

So when you issue `echo` without knowing exactly *which* Echo will be called — and that will depend on the running shell or if it is `exec`ed directly, not only on the system<sup>*</sup> itself —, you are rolling a die. It may not understand `-ne` as two flags and print it verbatim: That's what you observed.

Printf, on the other hand, [is *required* to interpret `\nnn` as the octal character "nnn"](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/printf.html). In your case, `\033` is the escape character and `\007` is the bell character; All else is to be taken literally. Therefore,

```
silent !printf '\%s' '\033]12;red\007'
autocmd VimLeave * silent !printf '\%s' '\033]112\007'
```

1. You actually don't even need the format specifier `%s` in this case, but it is good practice to always put it in (otherwise you may have a surprise if you insert `%` in the argument, for example).
2. In Vim the `%` itself must be escaped, otherwise it gets substituted with the current file's name.

<sup>*In my system I could only manage to reproduce your issue by inserting `set shell=/bin/dash` and `set t_te=` at the top of the sample `~/.vimrc` you provided.</sup>